# Sudoku Solution Using Multiprocessing

Tags: python-multiprocessing, backtracking, sudoku

I tried sudoku solution using backtracking, but it was taking a lot time around 12sec to give output. I tried to implement a multiprocessing technique but it's taking lot more time than that of backtracking. I never ran it completely it's too slow. Please suggest what am I missing? Even better if someone can also tell me how to run this through my GPU. (using CUDA).

```
import concurrent.futures
import copy

A = [[0]*9 for _ in range(9)]
A[0][6] = 2
A[1][1] = 8
A[1][5] = 7
A[1][7] = 9
A[2][0] = 6
A[2][2] = 2
A[2][6] = 5
A[3][1] = 7
A[3][4] = 6
A[4][3] = 9
A[4][5] = 1
A[5][4] = 2
A[5][7] = 4
A[6][2] = 5
A[6][6] = 6
A[6][8] = 3
A[7][1] = 9
A[7][3] = 4
A[7][7] = 7
A[8][2] = 6

Boards = [A]

L = []
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        if A[i][j] == 0:
            L.append([i,j])
            
def RC_Check(A,Value,N):
    global L
    i,j = L[N]
    
    for x in range(9):
        if A[x][j] == Value:
            return False
        if A[i][x] == Value:
            return False
    return True

def Square_Check(A,Value,N):
    global L
    i,j = L[N]
    
    X, Y = int(i/3)*3,int(j/3)*3
    for x in range(X,X+3):
        for y in range(Y,Y+3):
            if A[x][y] == Value:
                return False
    return True

def New_Boards(Board,N):
    global L
    i,j = L[N]

    Boards = []
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        RC_Process = executor.map(RC_Check,[Board]*10,list(range(1,10)),[N]*10)
        Square_Process = executor.map(Square_Check,[Board]*10,list(range(1,10)),[N]*10)

        for Value, (RC_Process, Square_Process) in enumerate(zip(RC_Process,Square_Process)):
            if RC_Process and Square_Process:
                Board[i][j] = Value+1
                Boards.append(copy.deepcopy(Board))

    return Boards

def Solve_Boards(Boards,N):
    Results = []
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        Process = executor.map(New_Boards,Boards,[N]*len(Boards))

        for new_boards in Process:
            if len(new_boards):
                Results.extend(new_boards)

    return Results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 0
    while N < len(L):
        Boards = Solve_Boards(Boards,N)
        N+=1
        print(len(Boards),N)
print(Boards)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi processing is *NOT* a silver bullet. Backtracking is pretty more efficient than exhaustive search parallelly in most cases. I tried running this code on my PC which has 32 cores 64 threads, but it takes long time.

And you look like to want to use GPGPU to solve this problem, but i doesn't suit, Because state of board depends on previous state, so can't split calculation efficiently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification, but as most of the time is being taken in calculation of next available boards. We can use GPU for calculating those next available boards parallelly each time until the solution is found. Wont that be effective? I think GPU is much much faster so running it on GPU should be able to save ample amount of time. Or even if we do it, it will be taking longer time than backtracking?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field, but I assume number of sudoku input patterns are quite much than number of GPU units. Even [QUADRO RTX 8000](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/design-visualization/quadro/rtx-8000/) has only 4,608 cores. On the other hand, [Sudoku solutions are 6\.67×10^21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku) if search exhaustively. Which can do it must be only quantum computer.